# How to kill a child process started by process in java?

Tags: java, process

In the below code snippet, if I destroy `Process p` using `p.destroy()` only process `p`(i.e.`cmd.exe`) is getting destroyed. But not its child `iperf.exe`. How to terminate this process in Java.

```
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c iperf -s > testresult.txt");
```

Comment: Don't use `Runtime.exec()`, use a `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: let the main process wait for the child process 
p.waitFor();
p.destroy(); 
then terminate all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 7 [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) can do the redirection for you, so just run iperf directly rather than through `cmd.exe`.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("iperf", "-s");
pb.redirectOutput(new File("testresult.txt"));
Process p = pb.start();
```

The resulting `p` is now itext itself, so `destroy()` will work as you require.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this code instead:

```
Process p= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("iperf -s");
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("testresult.txt");
byte[] bytes;
in.read(bytes);
out.write(bytes);
```

This code will not work exactly, but you just need to fiddle with the streams a little.

Comment: But I need to destroy child process(iperf). How to do that? Any idea?

Comment: Just `p.destroy()`. I've seperated cmd.exe and iperf, so iperf will be killed upon `p.destroy()`.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer following code snippet:

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {


    final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");

        //if killed abnormally ( For Example using ^C from cmd)
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                process.destroy();
                System.out.println(" notepad killed ");
            }


        });





}
}
```

Comment: This answer is **NOT** correct. Please check the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook-java.lang.Thread-) of `Runtime` class. This code will clean up the spawned processes only when the JVM is shut down gracefully.